# Is it unsafe to use /etc/hosts file as a website blocker in the following manner?

Tags: linux, http, hosts-file

I'm a linux noob, and while looking for a simple OS-level website blocking technique, I came upon the solution of using the linux hosts file like so:

```
127.0.0.1 websiteiwanttoblock.com
127.0.0.1 anotherone.com
...
```

This is nice and simple - perfect for my purposes, but here's my question: If I often use `127.0.0.1` for web development purposes, is this dangerous?

It seems that, at the very least it could mess up the web dev project I'm currently working on? For example, if Chrome/Firefox makes a request to `websiteiwanttoblock.com/api/blah`, then would that make a request `127.0.0.1/api/blah` and potentially mess with my project's api?

If this is dangerous in that regard, is there a safer "null" ip address that I could redirect blocked sites to? I know it's probably not good practice to use the hosts file like this, but I just love the simplicity of editing a text file rather than downloading a package or whatever.

Edit: Oh, and I often use port 3000 for dev stuff, but let's assume that I sometimes use 80, or any other available port number.

Comment: Not really! I use `\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` to block Reddit, Facebook, YouTube and a bunch of others! Everyone should! In order to perform a XSS attack, someone would have to hack a public site they know you do visit, create a link to a site they know you block, and exploit a vulnerability in your development software. They would have to access your system in the first place to know the last two bits of info. The odds are so astronomical it would be easier to hack your OS directly. I never worry because my dev software is always secure :).

Comment: Use 10.10.10.10 instead of 127.0.0.1, bind 10.10.10.10 to eth0:1 (or enp4s0:1 or whatever your adapter is called), and configure your webserver not to listen on 10.10.10.10. That'll provide you with a "safer" IP to redirect to which doesn't need iptables. To expand on this, use distinct 10.x.y.z addresses for each host, have your webserver listen on all of them, and log the request including IP so you get an idea which of the blocked sites got which request, and when.

Comment: Whether or not secure, it's a dirty hack. etc/hosts is not for blocking outbound traffic. That's what a firewall (ipf or iptables) is for.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm Why not use 0.0.0.0 instead?

Comment: @jamesdlin: because you want an address that's known to be served by exactly one distinct device (that will reject the connection). Try `ssh 0.0.0.0`, then call `netstat`, you'll see a connection from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1. It's kind of hard to tell your webserver to serve requests from localhost, but refuse these 0.0.0.0 requests.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Short Answer

**Is it *safe* to use the `/etc/hosts` file as a website blocking "null" address?**

I would argue the answer should be: **No.**

If for no other reason than the requests are not actually "nulled".  They are still active requests.  And as the OP indicates, since the requests are for legitimate Internet hosts, this sort of short cut method of redirecting requests to `localhost` may interfere with testing networking code in a development environment.

Perhaps a better method of blocking traffic to and from certain Internet hosts, is to utilize `iptables` which is the interface to the Linux kernel's firewall.  `iptables` is the default networking rule table for most GNU/Linux systems.  Some distros use `ufw` as a front-end to `iptables`.

If you want to use `iptables`, here's a simple script which will `DROP` all incoming and outgoing packets for a list of IP addresses or hostnames with one address or hostname per line contained in a plain text file called `~/blocking.txt`

```
## Block every IP address in ~/blocking.txt
## DROP incoming packets to avoid information leak about your hosts firewall
## (HT to Conor Mancone) REJECT outgoing packets to avoid browser wait
for i in $(cat ~/blocking.txt); do
    echo "Blocking all traffic to and from $i"    
    /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s $i -j DROP
    /sbin/iptables -I OUTPUT -d $i -j REJECT
done
```

Sample `~/blocking.txt`

```
websiteiwanttoblock.com
anotherone.com
ip.add.of.net/mask
```

**Do not place your `localhost` IP addresses in this file.**

## Longer Answer

While reassigning Internet hosts to `localhost` in the `/etc/hosts` file is a common short cut technique to *block* unwanted Internet hosts, this method has some serious security drawbacks.

#### Incoming requests

Incoming requests which were not purposefully initiated via a specific user request.  The most common example is ads on webpages.  Let's follow the incoming packets...

First, I start up `wireshark`.  Then I place the biggest Internet ad company in my `/etc/hosts` file with this line:

```
127.0.0.1   google.com
```

And then disable all ad blockers in my browser, navigate to `youtube` and play any random video.

If I filter my packets, broadly including Google's IP address space:

```
ip.addr==172.217.0.0/16
```

I am still receiving packets from Google.

What does this mean?

It means that there is a possibility of a malicious server inserting malware which may be able to attack my computing platform via packets that are still arriving and sent to localhost.  The use of `/etc/hosts` rather than dropping or rejecting the packets via the firewall rules, is a poor security measure.  It does not *block* incoming packets from possible malicious hosts, nor does it provide effective feedback for trouble shooting purposes.

#### Outgoing requests

Outgoing requests which are sent to `localhost` rather than being rejected or dropped by the firwall rules are still being processed by the kernel.  There are a few undesirable actions that occur when `/etc/hosts` is used rather than the firewall:

- Extra processing is occurring when the outgoing packet hits localhost.  For example, if a webserver is running on the host, the packet sent to localhost may be processed by the webserver.
- The feedback from outgoing requests may become confusing if the `/etc/hosts` is populated with certain domains.

#### iptables can handle lots of rules

According to some:

[ServerFault: How many rules can iptables support](https://serverfault.com/questions/479549/how-many-rules-can-iptables-support)

A possible theoretical limit on a 32-bit machine is 38 million rules.  However, as noted in the referenced post, as the `iptables` rule list expands so does the needed kernel memory.

Comment: It is better to use `REJECT` rather than `DROP`.  `DROP` simply ignores it, which causes the system that made the request to continue to wait for a response.  `REJECT` both ignores the request and sends a notice to the person who requested it telling them that the request was blocked.  The practical difference is that if you accidentally load up a website in your browser with `DROP`, your browser will show a loading screen forever.  For `REJECT`, you will immediately get an error in your browser.  The latter is much more convenient, IMO.

Comment: Is `iptables` really suitable for 100k+ hosts? I figured as a traffic routing (and not just DNS) service it'd destroy performance off any traffic what so ever if it goes badly, not just the initial resolution.

Comment: @Sirens  No iptables by itself will be terrbile with 100k hosts.  YOu need to combine ipset with iptables for more than about 1k-2k depending on your CPU.  ipset create banned_hosts hash:net family inet hashsize 524288 maxelem 800000 counters comment  and iptables -I INPUT 1 -m set --match-set banned_hosts src -j DROP

Comment: What's the security concern though? If someone has the power to execute code on your local machine and run ON A PRIVILEGED PORT it doesn't matter where you're routing it because they can just intercept and modify all your traffic anyways by installing a CA or just bootstrapping the SSL APIs

Comment: @RubberStamp  iptables can physically handle tons of rules, but I had a 4 core 2.#Ghz, and using iptables as a block list for approx 2100 ip's resulted all 4 cores running at 99% and bandwidth dropping to 2k/s.

Comment: @cybernard: you may need to examine the complexity of the rules in your `iptables` ... I run some small test servers running dual core, 2GB RAM, and `iptables` with about 10,000 rules... no problems at all.  .... The simple `DROP` and `REJECT` rules proposed above should not have a significant memory or processor footprint.

Comment: https://workshop.netfilter.org/2013/wiki/images/a/ab/Jozsef_Kadlecsik_ipset-osd-public.pdf   This pdf on page 10 has a graph indicating the performance difference.  Besides the readability and management of iptables if easier with ipset.  Also ipset has additonal features like automatic timeout, and statistical packet, byte tracking.  That can be saved, and not lost when rebooting.

Comment: [Useless use of backticks.](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks)

Comment: If I may suggest a bit of improvement here, `for i in $(cat ~/blocking.txt); do` is kinda poor style in shell scripts. One, that's [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) and two, it won't output lines properly with leading tabs/spaces. De-facto standard is via `while IFS= read -r line; do...done < input.txt` or better `while IFS='' read -r l || [ -n "$l" ];do...done<input.txt` to handle files without newline at the end of file.  See also [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Or [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401762/85039) if you want to use for loops.

Comment: Actually there are good reasons to use DROP rather than REJECT in firewall rules. DROP looks to an attacker like there is no computer present. REJECT confirms there is a working system listening at that IP address and it may be worth trying different attack vectors. For that reason it's common on servers to DROP ping and other identity confirming messages to minimise the server's visibility to script kiddies.

Comment: From a purist's point of view, only REJECT should be used and DROP is not neighbourly. From a practical point of view, matt is absolutely right. And this is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: @RubberStamp This is a great answer, but could be worded better. "If for no other reason than the requests are not actually 'nulled'." This statement makes it seem like that's your strongest argument.

Comment: I would argue that using IPTables does not have the same effect. Ads/malware can/will change IP addresses, whereas the hostname is less likely to change (if not for malware, at least for well-known ad servers).

Comment: @korockinout13: `$man iptables` ...  "Address  can be either a network name, a hostname, a network IP address (with /mask), or a plain IP address."

Comment: @RubberStamp correct, but those hostnames are only resolved once when the rule is loaded. It doesn't help for things that change or resolve to multiple addresses, like here. https://serverfault.com/a/508694/

Answer (score 11):

> [...] while looking for a simple OS-level website blocking technique, I came upon the solution of using the linux hosts file [...]

To clarify, `/etc/hosts` just maps hostnames to IP addresses. An entry with `127.0.0.1` doesn't block your access to the server, it just makes your computer locally resolve that particular name to `127.0.0.1`. You and the server could still be exchanging packets without restrictions.

> If I often use `127.0.0.1` for web development purposes, is this dangerous? It seems that, at the very least it could mess up the web dev project I'm currently working on?

No, resolving to `127.0.0.1` doesn't put you in additional danger. That's because a website can have their name be resolved to any IP anyway, including `127.0.0.1` (unless the DNS server blocks that). So if `evilpage.example` wanted to resolve to `127.0.0.1`, they could just specify a respective DNS `A` record and wouldn't have to rely on your `/etc/hosts`. (Also see: [Is it safe to have a DNS record pointing to 127.0.0.1?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36491/is-it-safe-to-have-a-dns-record-pointing-to-127-0-0-1))

Note that running something on `127.0.0.1` may make you vulnerable to [DNS rebinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding) attacks.

Answer (score 3):

Unless your webserver is running on port 80 or 443 on your local machine (`127.0.0.1`), then that shouldn't affect your web project. If it is though, then it could be an annoyance. If you sent a request to `http://example.com/api/`, then it would end up sending a request to `http://127.0.0.1/api/`. If you have a resource called `/api/`, then it would end up receiving the request and thus interfering with your app.
But the biggest point that I would like to stress that @Arminus mentioned was that the `/etc/hosts/` file is for mapping IP addresses to hostnames. 
If you want to block a particular host, I would suggest installing a firewall such as UFW or using the default Linux firewall, iptables. 
Here are some links to help you get started:

UFW: https://www.linux.com/learn/introduction-uncomplicated-firewall-ufw

iptables: https://www.howtogeek.com/177621/the-beginners-guide-to-iptables-the-linux-firewall/

Comment: If you're looking to launch your app into a production environment, look at this: https://www.quora.com/What-are-good-open-source-firewalls-for-Linux

Comment: For even better iptables documentation:  https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use an IP address that should not go *anywhere*, you can use the official [documentation IP addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737):

- 192.0.2.0/24
- 198.51.100.0/24
- 203.0.113.0/24

It's still possible that they go somewhere, but they SHOULD be added to non-routable address spaces. As others have noted, that *potentially* will only route your traffic to those IP addresses - there are better solutions mentioned in the other answers, but these at least won't go to your *local* machine.

Answer (score 0):

The entire 127.0.0.0/8 address range is localhost so you can block outgoing traffic for one address in this range for example 127.1.1.1.

Then use the hosts file to redirect unwanted traffic to this address so unwanted tracking requests won't hammer your webserver running on localhost.